# Wait RxJava response

Tags: android, multithreading, kotlin, rx-java2, kotlin-coroutines

Think about this func1() is in another java class, you can reach it by callback. My problem is I want to wait the func1 result. How can I do that?

```
launch{
    func1()

    func2()
    func3()

    // I want to catch the data here, so it should wait here but because of using rxjava (another thread), I cannot control it. 
    // I know if I use new retrofit libs, I can use coroutines, but right now, I cannot change old ones. 

    //My problem is I want to wait the func1 result here. How can I do that?
}

suspend fun func2(){}
suspend fun func3(){}

//Another java class
public Single<MyData> func1(){
    apiClient.getMyData()
    .subscribe(myData -> {
        // Let's say this takes 5 seconds to get the data
    }, throwable -> {

    });
}
```

Comment: if `func1` returns `Single` you can just call `blockingGet` to wait while it completes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the library

`implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-rx2:$coroutine_version"`

Then call,

`func1().await()`

Read more [here](https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.coroutines/blob/master/reactive/kotlinx-coroutines-rx2/README.md)